# Exception ocurred during loading

Tags: java, salesforce, etl, soql

Getting NullPointer errors when using CLIq tool for apex data loader,

Trying to run following SOQL query pointing to one of our developer sandbox

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, EmployeeNumber, EmployeeNumber__c, ManagerID,    Manager.FirstName, Manager.LastName, Manager.Email FROM User WHERE IsActive=True AND ManagerID<>null
```

2013-10-18 13:45:17,557 ERROR [test] action.AbstractAction handleException (Abst
ractAction.java:199) - **Exception occured during loading**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.SOQLMapper.getReferenceField(SOQLMa
pper.java:223)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.SOQLMapper.evalSfdcField(SOQLMapper
.java:191)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.SOQLMapper.evalSfdcField(SOQLMapper
.java:185)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.SOQLMapper.normalizeSoql(SOQLMapper
.java:169)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.SOQLMapper.addSoqlFieldMapping(SOQL
Mapper.java:165)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.mapping.SOQLMapper.initSoqlMapping(SOQLMapp
er.java:130)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.AbstractExtractAction.getDaoColumns(
AbstractExtractAction.java:88)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.AbstractExtractAction.initOperation(
AbstractExtractAction.java:139)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractActio
n.java:117)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.executeAction(Control
ler.java:121)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.jav
a:149)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.jav
a:100)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.ja
va:253)
2013-10-18 13:45:17,559 ERROR [test] progress.NihilistProgressAdapter doneError
(NihilistProgressAdapter.java:58) -
```

Any hints will be very appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a chance that one for the requested or filter fields are primitives in java but hold `null` you database?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response, it might be possible, I'm not a Java expert but i assume you'r pointing to the right direction, probably it's trying to create metadata from lookups being null, for the time being I just moved forward and did it without this tool, here is the guide I used for future reference http://www.developerforce.com/media/Cheatsheet_Setting_Up_Automated_Data_Loader_9_0.pdf